# fpga implementation of lfsr for random sequence generation

Tags: vhdl, fpga

i am working with random sequence generation using lfsr. I want to show the output sequence on fpga board.So for that should i have to map my I/Os to actual pins on board using .ucf file. is that sufficient to show my o/p on board or should i have to do more than that like to use oscilloscope to show the o/p sequence.

Comment: I think this question cannot be answered without more context. How you display the sequence is up to your requirements. Do you want to just show that the sequence is pseudo random or do you have to prove anything, is it just for show or do you need the output for something else,...

Comment: i want to use this sequence in another programm but before that i want to show that different sequences gets generated for different input seed.